# How to handle border and background in compose shape?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-button

In the code the image border only on the sides, not on the corners.
for the button, the background goes out of the shape/border.
I only managed to "fix" the button by using a fixed height but I don't understand why a fixed height help and I wonder if there is another way to do this.

```
@Composable
fun Test(){
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_close),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
                .size(20.dp)
        )
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = {  },
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Green)
        ) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `Image`, remove the `clip` modifier and use the `shape` inside the `border` parameter:

```
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_xxx),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            //.clip(CircleShape)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Red, CircleShape)
            .size(20.dp)
    )
```

[image]

For the `OutlinedButton` use the `colors` attribute to assign the background color instead of the `Modifier.background`

```
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {  },
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            //.clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            //.background(Color.Green),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(backgroundColor = Green),
    )
```

[image]